# mixed output in reading .csv file

Tags: r

I'm trying to read the first 1000 lines of  a .csv file, but I encountered with a problem.
the output is very is mixed. the columns are less than you would expect.

I did following thig

```
data<-read.csv("myfile", header=T, sep=",", nrow=1000)
```

the output is like this :

```
> data[1:10,]
   TranscriptId         GeneId.name. Mirna.Name.miRBase.version. miTG.score
1      F52F10.2   F52F10.2(F52F10.2)              cel-miR-62(33)      0.488
2          UTR3    V:1550484-1550512         0.00994712053496221         NA
3      F11A1.3a      F11A1.3(daf-12)              cel-miR-62(33)      0.702
4          UTR3  X:10665625-10665653          0.0247451317964074         NA
5      T11G6.5a     T11G6.5(T11G6.5)              cel-miR-62(33)      0.511
6           CDS IV:10841175-10841203           0.022290972286146         NA
7           CDS IV:10840760-10840788          0.0110658552017645         NA
8       F28H6.4     F28H6.4(F28H6.4)              cel-miR-62(33)      0.494
9          UTR3  X:14133330-14133358         0.00425015346910806         NA
10          CDS  X:14128414-14128442          0.0140299826282741         NA
```

and I would expect that **UTR** and **CDS** would be my colnames.
in other world, how can I rearrange about information and put them in in matrix like below? (I  just wrote one row of matrix here)

```
> data[1:1,]
   TranscriptId         GeneId.name.    Mirna.Name.miRBase.version.    miTG.score         UTR3           se
1      F52F10.2   F52F10.2(F52F10.2)              cel-miR-62(33)      0.488   V:1550484-1550512  0.00994712053496221
```

for multiple CDS and UTR3, we will take the one with the highest  score(3th column) in every record.

Comment: Why don't you also show the first few lines of your file? As it stands, there isn't enough info for us to help.

Comment: @flodel, I've updated it.

Comment: It is still not clear how `CDS` should be handled. It seems some records even have multiple `CDS` values, e.g. the one starting on e line 5 and spanning lines 5, 6, and 7.

Comment: @flodel, you are right, for every recod with multiple UTR3 or CDS, we simply will take the one with highest score(which means the value in the 3th column of respective row)

Comment: I saw you improved your question and reposted it so I hope this one will get closed. In general, know that reposts are frowned upon. It is recommended you edit and improve your original question.

Comment: @flodel, I didn't know it, sorry, How can I make it right ?

Comment: You can leave it alone, and the question will be closed. Or you can delete the question yourself.